# When i upload an image the dropdown menu become in a single and button also lost it's css (I am using material UI React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

As you can see in the below picture when i came to this page it look like this and it's perfectly fine as i want
[image]

but when i upload in image (using dropzoneArea) material UI it become look like this and all the drop down menu will be in single line and also you will see submit button also changed

[image]

uploadProduct.js

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

import {
  Typography,
  Grid,
  Button,
  FormGroup,
  TextField,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
  InputLabel,
  FormControl,
  InputAdornment,
  Input,
} from "@mui/material";
import "./styles.css";
import FileUpload from "../../utils/FileUpload";
import Axios from "axios";
import MuiPhoneNumber from "material-ui-phone-number";
import decode from "jwt-decode";

export const UploadProduct = (props) => {

  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();
  const [Token_Id, setToken_Id] = useState(localStorage.getItem("token"))
  const [Title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [userId, setuserId] = useState(0);
  const [Description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [Price, setPrice] = useState();
  const [Category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const [perGiven, setperGiven] = useState("");
  const [Phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [Address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [Name, setName] = useState("")
  const [Images, setImages] = useState([]);

  const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    history.push("/");
    setName("");
    props.showAlert("Logout Successfully", "success");
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    const token = Token_Id;
    if (token) {
      const { exp, name, id } = decode(token);
      setuserId(id)
      setName(name);
      if (Date.now() >= exp * 1000) {
        handleLogout();
      }
    }
    setToken_Id(localStorage.getItem("token"));
  }, [location]);
  
  const updateImages =  (newImages) => {
    setImages(newImages);
  };
  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (
      !userId ||
      !Name ||
      !Title ||
      !Description ||
      !Price ||
      !Category ||
      !perGiven ||
      !Phone ||
      !Address ||
      !Images
    ) {
      return alert("fill all the fields first!");
    }

    const variables = {
      userId: userId,
      userName: Name,
      title: Title,
      description: Description,
      category: Category,
      price: Price,
      rentType: perGiven,
      images: Images,
      phoneNumber: Phone,
      address: Address,
    };
    Axios.post("/product/uploadProduct", variables).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.success) {
        alert("Product Successfully Uploaded");
        history.push("/");
      } else {
        alert("Failed to upload Product");
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    
    <div
      className="parentDiv"
      style={{marginTop: "70px", paddingBottom: "10px" }}
    >
      <div style={{ maxWidth: "700px", margin: "2rem auto" }}>
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center", marginBottom: "2rem" }}>
          <Typography variant="h4">Anything for rent?</Typography>
        </div>

        <FormGroup>
          {/* DropZone */}
          <FileUpload refreshFunction={updateImages} />
          <br />
          <TextField
            variant="standard"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="title"
            label="AD TITLE"
            name="title"
            value={Title}
            autoFocus
            onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
          />
          <br />
          <TextField
            variant="standard"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="description"
            label="DESCRIPTION"
            name="description"
            value={Description}
            onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
          />
          <br />
          <FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ m: 0, minWidth: 120 }}>
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">
              CHOOSE CATEGORY
            </InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
              label="CHOOSE CATEGORY"
              name="category"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setCategory(e.target.value);
              }}
              className="input"
              style={{display: "flex", alignItems: "center"}}
            >
              <MenuItem value="">
                <em>None</em>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="Tools">Tools</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="Apparels">Apparels</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="Vehicles">Vehicles</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="Equipments">Equipments</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="Footwear">Footwear</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
          <br />
          <MuiPhoneNumber
            className="my-2"
            label="PHONE NUMBER"
            variant="standard"
            value={Phone}
            defaultCountry={"pk"}
            onChange={setPhone}
          />
          <br />
          <Grid container className="my-1">
            <Grid item>
              <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-amount">
                SET A PRICE
              </InputLabel>
              <Input
                id="standard-adornment-amount"
                required={true}
                value={Price}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setPrice(e.target.value);
                }}
                startAdornment={
                  <InputAdornment position="start">Rs</InputAdornment>
                }
              />
              {/* <TextField required  fullWidth id="price" label="Price" name="price" value={Price} onChange={(e) => {setPrice(e.target.value)}} variant="standard" /> */}
            </Grid>
            <Grid
              item
              className="mx-2"
              alignItems="stretch"
              style={{ display: "flex" }}
            >
              <FormControl
                className="my-1"
                variant="standard"
                sx={{ m: 2, minWidth: 150 }}
              >
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-standard-label">
                  Rent type
                </InputLabel>
                <Select
                  labelId="demo-simple-select-standard-label"
                  id="demo-simple-select-standard"
                  value={perGiven}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setperGiven(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  label="rent type"
                >
                  <MenuItem value="">
                    <em>None</em>
                  </MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Day">Day</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Week">Week</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Month">Month</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <TextField
            className="my-2"
            variant="standard"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="address"
            label="ADDRESS"
            name="address"
            value={Address}
            onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
          />
          <Button className="my-3" variant="contained" onClick={onSubmit}>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </FormGroup>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

FileUpload.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { DropzoneArea } from "material-ui-dropzone";

import Axios from "axios";
function FileUpload(props) {
  const [Images, setImages] = useState([]);

  const onDrop = (files) => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    const config = {
      header: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
    };
    formData.append("file", files[0]);
    //save the Image we chose inside the Node Server
    Axios.post("/product/uploadImage", formData, config).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.success) {
        setImages([...Images, response.data.image]);
        props.refreshFunction([...Images, response.data.image]);
      } else {
        alert("Failed to save the Image in Server");
      }
    });
  };

  const onDelete = (image) => {
    const currentIndex = Images.indexOf(image);

    let newImages = [...Images];
    newImages.splice(currentIndex, 1);

    setImages(newImages);
    props.refreshFunction(newImages);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
      <DropzoneArea
        onDrop={onDrop}
        multiple={false}
        maxSize={5000000}
        showPreviewsInDropzone={false}
      >
        {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
          <div
            style={{
              width: "300px",
              height: "240px",
              border: "1px solid lightgray",
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
            {...getRootProps()}
          >
            <input {...getInputProps()} />
          </div>
        )}
      </DropzoneArea>

      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          marginLeft: "10px",
          width: "350px",
          height: "250px",
          overflowX: "scroll",
        }}
      >
        {Images.map((image, index) => (
          <div onClick={() => onDelete(image)}>
            <img
              style={{ minWidth: "200px", width: "220px", height: "230px" }}
              src={`http://localhost:5000/${image}`}
              alt={`productImg-${index}`}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FileUpload;
```

As you can see in the UploadProduct.js i called the FileUpload component for uploading the files.
If you find any error or bug please let me know and any suggestion will be helpfull
TIA